# Popup view to choose image

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to create an example like the image below but instead have a choose image from Photo Library or Take a Picture with camera (like facebook app). Is this view something built-in or do I need to create a custom view?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want a UIActionSheet?

Do this:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
                                  initWithTitle:@"What do you want to do?" 
                                  delegate:self 
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                  destructiveButtonTitle:nil 
                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Camera", @"Photos", nil];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    [actionSheet release];
```

Then in the clickedButtonAtIndex do something like this:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;

    if ([[actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex] isEqualToString:@"Camera"]) {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera; 
    } 
    else if ([[actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex] isEqualToString:@"Photos"]) {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    }
   [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
   [picker release];
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes! Thank you very much, I didn't know that's what they were called so I had a hard time searching for info.